# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchProfile'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this warning and I was wondering what steps I need to take to remove the warning from my console.  The issue being, I am using the fetchProfile() function elsewhere so I can't move it within the useEffect.  any suggestions?  My code is as follows:

```
  const fetchProfile = async () => {
    const token = await localStorage.FBIdToken
    await axios
      .get(`/user`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        setUser(res.data)
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          github: res.data.user.github ? res.data.user.github : '',
          website: res.data.user.website ? res.data.user.website : '',
          linkedIn: res.data.user.linkedIn ? res.data.user.linkedIn : '',
          cohort: res.data.user.cohort,
          program: res.data.user.program
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('error'))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProfile()
  }, [])
```

Comment: also adding fetch profile into the dependency array does not remove the warning

Comment: Is your `fetchProfile` function defined _within_ the component?

Comment: Yes my fetch profile has been defined within the component

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the function in `useCallback` and adding it as a dependency should work, like so:

```
const fetchProfile = useCallback(async () => {
  // Do request as per normal
}, [])

useEffect(fetchProfile, [fetchProfile])
```

Another option is to move the `fetchProfile` function *outside* the component and pass in the setters to the call:

```
// This is defined outside your component
const fetchProfile = async ({ setUser, setFormData }) => {
  // Do request as per normal
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchProfile({ setUser, setFormData })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the warning because you're using `fetchProfile` inside your hook, but not including it in the dependencies. If `fetchProfile` changes, your effect won't run.

To get rid of the warning, add `fetchProfile` to the dependencies (the second argument to `useEffect()`):

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchProfile()
}, [fetchProfile])
```